# Binary Tree using int array as key (Euclidean distances)?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, euclidean-distance

Have written a Binary Search Tree that stores data on ships, the key for the search is their acoustic signature.

When searching the tree I want to return either a ship with the correct signature or the one with the closest match to the searched signature. (By seeing which ship has the closest Euclidean distance).

The problem I am having is how to compare the signatures other than their actual numerical value. Which would then mean that any search performed would be sequential and not binary?

Any ideas?

Comment: Suppose you pick some ordering scheme when you form the tree, and you end up with signature A as the key for node A, and signature B for the key at node B, where A < B in your ordering, so B is in the right subtree from A. For any such pair of signatures, after the tree is formed, I can create an artificial signature such that the Euclidean distance from A is larger than it is from B (just pick a signature very very close to B's signature).. and thus you would have wanted B to be in the *left* subtree of A.

Comment: That is the problem I am having, I cannot see a way around only being able to use a binary search on the data if it /is/ in the tree and sequential search (where you calculate every euclidean distance) if it's not the tree.

Comment: The problem is that binary search trees assume the ordering of the nodes is fixed at the time the tree is created, and won't change later for indexing/looking things up in the tree. This is not the right data structure for you if you want to be able to search elements with changing orderings, and Euclidean distance from a variable query signature would count as a changing ordering. When the query changes, the ordering of the stored data changes. You need a structure that minimizes how much penalty you pay for changing that ordering. The answer below suggested Kd-trees, which seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing comes down to a [nearest-neighbour search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) in multiple dimensions. You can't solve this efficiently with just a binary tree; you'll need some space partitioning structure.

If your array length N is small (single digits), you can use a 2^N-ary tree (quadtree, octree, ...) as a generalization of a binary tree.

A popular choice which also works well for higher dimensions is a [Kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).